# Is it worth switching from V brakes to disc brakes?

Tags: brakes, disc-brake, rims

The bike that I am getting has v brakes and I was wondering if it would be worth the money to get disc brakes for it. Can someone please help me here?

Comment: Possible dupe of https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4423/converting-bike-from-rim-brakes-to-disc-brakes and https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/50124/giant-terrago-26-inch-can-i-have-disc-brakes and https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/57237/could-i-have-the-brakes-changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, check the frame and fork have disc mounts. It will probably have IS disc mounts on both as the bike was also offered as a disc option.

Then, check that the wheels have a mounting point for disc brake rotors. Some bikes from this era had both rim-brake rims and disc hubs but if there's nowhere to bolt on discs, you will need new wheels. This is where the costs start to spiral.

If the frame and wheels are good to go, hydraulic disc brakes can offer more control and often more power but you get what you pay for. There are certainly advantages for offroad riding in wet/muddy conditions especially. However, V-brakes are a very powerful system and will stop you. They are very cheap to maintain (until your wheel rim wears out) too.

If you go ahead, the caliper and lever usually come together with the hose, pre bled, but needing to be cut down. You also generally need IS-Post Mount adaptors and disc rotors in the sizes you want (up to 180mm supported by fork)

Comment: Thanks Joe. You really know what you're talking about.

Comment: Thanks @James. I used to run the workshop for a trek dealer!

Comment: Really. That sounds fun! I wish I could do that. I'm only in high school so can't do that yet . . .

Answer (score 1):

No.

Disk brakes require mounts on the frame, and a frame engineered to take those loads.

You'll also need new wheels that have mounts on the hub for rotors.

You would need rotors, calipers, and brake levers, plus hydraulics or cables.  All this will cost a significant amount, and be replacing 3/4 of your bike.

Instead, buy the bike you want originally, or just use your rim brakes.  There's nothing inherently wrong with rim brakes, they're just not as trendy.

Comment: By the sounds of it this would be expensive. It's nice having people like you guys who know what you're talking about.

Comment: @James  If the bike is free, just ride it as-is and do basic maintenance.  In a year or so you'll know what you want from your bike and can look for something you do want (disks, unseized suspension, whatever gearing you choose)

Comment: thanks for the tips. I'll ride this bike as is I just don't want it to fall apart when I'm riding on the trails.